# SQL Table Column information probing

Tags: .net, sql, database

Is there a way to get for a particular table in an SQL DataBase, the information containing the type and the size of any one column.

For example, having table T, with columns C1 being varchar(50) and C2 being Int and C3 being Bits(6). Is there a way to query the DB for that information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found this: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/04/27/60574.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can query in a number of ways, including:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
    NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'
```

There's a few more columns in that view, but you get the jist :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is:

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''
  AND COLUMN_NAME = ''